# AnyLogic: Opening sample model always opens my modified model instead - how to fix?

Tags: anylogic

I transformed the sample model into AnyLogic, because of errors I decided to close the model and reopen the sample one, but when I left I saved the modified one, now when I open the sample model, my transformed model is opened

I tried to close AnyLogic and open it again, but the modified model still opens

Answer (score 0):

You have overwritten the original. Either uninstall and reinstall AnyLogic or contact support@anylogic.com and ask them to send you the original model you need.

Comment: Most sample models (maybe all?) are also available in the AL Cloud https://cloud.anylogic.com/ , the source files can be downloaded from there too